# Scroll-behavior not found

Tags: html, css

I'm learning web development on my own. I'm trying to implement a smooth scroll effect in an html page using the scroll-behavior property. But my visual studio keeps prompting me with the message "Validation(CSS 4.0): scroll-behavior is not a know CSS property name".

Comment: I guess it's because the property is not already final, it's still as "working draft" status https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior#Specifications

Comment: `scroll-behavior` is not supported on most browsers yet https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scroll-behavior